# How to efficiently make a game for web and mobile with Laravel

Tags: php, database, api, laravel, mobile

Years ago I started making my own browsergame, in raw PHP with a bit of Javascript. That was it. But times has changed and since the initial release of the game years ago, mobile development became more and more important. Now I want to translate my game from the raw, self-written PHP to a more stable version, and I want to make it available for mobile too as a native app. There are two important things I want to change to my game:

- I'm currently transforming the game from raw PHP to the Laravel 5 framework. That way I don't need to write all code about authentication and so on by myself any more. I want to implement socket.io for the realtime data (and I'm thinking about AngularJS for a single page experience, but I'm not sure about that yet).
- And, I want to create a mobile experience: the game should be playable on mobile devices. I already started using Unity3D for it.

Both versions (web and mobile) should call an API that handles all the CRUD and safety checks. But there I have a problem: I want to save myself work so I want to write as few as possible duplicate code for the web- and mobile version. I want the webfront-end and the Unity game all to communicate with the same API.

Let's have an example: I have an http://api.example.com/?check=login&... that checks if the right user credentials are given. I think it is a good way to make this API with Lumen (the Laravel child). Well, I know how to send this request from Unity to the api. But how do I do this within the Laravel webversion? I mean, the Laravel web version should connect to the api, otherwise I have to rewrite the logincheck for both web and mobile instead of one central place. Or is there a much better option? I'm a bit tired of all the information and possible things so I hope you can make something more clear :)

So, to summarize my question and make it not too broad:

- **1) I'm a newbie in developing for web and mobile: am I thinking the right way?**
- **2) If it's possible: what is the best way to interact with one code base (/api) with both the web- and mobile version? Should I use a seperate api.example.com domain that handles everything. Or can the mobile game communicatie with the normal Laravel application?**

I really hope you can help me, or please let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: I would have used the REST style to code the api and deliver the data as Json and to authenticate I would use token authentication. Look at this tutorial for laravel.: https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51

Answer (score 0):

You can have the same API for your web and mobile versions and use [JSON Web Tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) for authentication - so that way you don't have to manage user state via cookies and other browser-locked mechanisms which make it difficult to reconcile between the mobile platform and web.

So the game and browser can communicate normally with the Laravel app over your API if you go the JWT route.

There's [Dingo](https://github.com/dingo/api) you can use for your API, and also [a nice JWT wrapper](https://github.com/francescomalatesta/laravel-api-boilerplate-jwt) for Laravel which itself uses Dingo. I've used it in production with ReactJS in a SPA to great effect.

Hard to answer without knowing everything yo are trying to achieve, and the specifics of your game - hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! Another question: what if I want the API to run on Lumen because that one is faster? Can I use Dingo for that one too?

Comment: Yes, Dingo works with Lumen too. According to the [description](https://github.com/dingo/api) they call it *A RESTful API package for the Laravel and Lumen frameworks*

Comment: I mean my main application in Laravel and the API in Lumen. Simultaneously.

Comment: Dingo works with both so shouldn't be a problem. You can have your main Laravel app also call the Lumen API instead of replicating the functionality.